# How do you deploy a Visual Studio project template that has a wizard?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix, project-template

I  have a Project Template that I want to make available to people that I work with. How should project templtes (and item templates) be deployed? According to MSDN on this page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) you should use a vsix package, but template wizards must be installed to the GAC and a vsix package cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't need the GAC after all. See:

Using IWizard in an item template without installing assembly in GAC?
[Using IWizard in an item template without installing assembly in GAC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244185/using-iwizard-in-an-item-template-without-installing-assembly-in-gac/16894895)